# Usb Wireless Adapter wrong ip address

Tags: networking, ip, linux-networking, wifi

I am Using Fedora (fc25.x86_64) .

The Wireless adapter (MT7601U Wireless Adapter 802.11n) connects to the Wireless WiFi successfully but no internet connection is got. 

I noticed that the wireless device is not assigned with the proper ip address/netmask  wich it shoulds be 192.168.1.X/255.255.255.X

```
wlp0s26u1u2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.93.203  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
```

How to fix This ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats a self assigned IP. 
- You could manually assign IP address in the USD device network settings(Don't know which device)
- Or Make sure DHCP is enable on both devices.(Router and USB device)